# DynamoDb access for unauthenticated users

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I want to store some analytical information about the use of mobile apps into Amazon DynamoDb. I have the following requirements:

- exactly one DynamoDb table per one mobile app
- an app can do only `PutItem` method
- all users of apps are unauthenticated (guests)

To provide to mobile apps a way to access a table in DynamoDb I see two options:

1. hardcode credentials with limited permissions into apps (permissions to do `PutItem` to a specific table);
2. use Amazon Cognito to get temporary credentials for unauthenticated users in runtime.

The second option Amazon strongly recommends as a much more secure. In my case a malicious user can either get access to hardcoded credentials or to a hardcoded identity pool ID with the same result: getting access to an AWS resource.

Question: does the use of Cognito in my case give any security improvements and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito identity is totally free - you wouldn't have to pay anything.

Your point that using Cognito doesn't add any security to unauthenticated requests isn't correct. From the Cognito FAQs:

---

**Q: How does Cognito Identity help me access AWS services securely?**

Cognito Identity assigns your users a set of temporary, limited privilege credentials to access your AWS resources. You can use Cognito Identity to securely access other AWS services from your mobile app without requiring your AWS account credentials. You can also use the unique identifier generated for your app users in your Identity and Access Management policies. For example you can create a policy for an S3 bucket that only allows a particular user access to their own folder.

---

The same thing described for S3 can be done with dynamo - see [this blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies) for specifics.

Comment: What I want to understand why hardcoding `ID` of an identity pool which provides temporary credentials for anybody is more secure than hardcoding credentials. A potential attacker can read either credentials or an identity pool ID and get access to AWS resources. And I can see no difference what to delete in such a case: the pool or the credentials. BTW Cognito identities are not for free but [cost a lot](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/).

Comment: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2XEKZCNBM7U64/How-Amazon-Cognito-Keeps-Mobile-App-Users-Data-Safe covers that to some degree, then as described in the blog post linked above, you can use that id to scope what a user can see with IAM. Cognito federated identities (which is what you're asking about, what an identity pool is for, and what gives credentials) are free, Cognito user pools (which you linked) are not. I'm a developer on the Cognito team - what you're trying to do is free.

Comment: From your link: "Using the Federated Identities feature for authenticating users and generating unique identifiers is always free with Amazon Cognito."

Comment: Thank you for comments.  1) I agree that use of Cognito definitely provides a lot of benefits in general but I still don't see any security improvements in my case. Therefore I edited my questions to make stress on exactly my requirements. 2) I don't understand from Cognito pricing that what I'm trying to do is free. Should I ask tech support?

Comment: 1) What is your use case for using dynamo and only giving put power to users? 2) If you're using user pools, there are payments. If you're only using federated identities (identity pools, you get credentials...etc.), it's totally free.

Comment: 1) In my use case some information about work of mobile applications are collected into DynamoDb and then processed by a service in the Amazon cloud. This is our internal service so there is no problem of providing credentials. 2) I got the difference between user pools and identity pools, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into using something like mobile analytics or kinesis instead of dynamo?

Comment: Yes I have, but currently DynamoDb fits better into our needs. BTW let's make the decision about my question. The answer should be 'No'?

Comment: Cognito identity is not free. why do you think that?

Comment: Cognito user pools and sync are not free, cognito identity (now federated identities) is free. Source: I work on cognito.

Comment: Sorry I only looked at the link here https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/?nc1=f_ls and it shows 50k MAUs are free. either the url is not up to date.

Comment: It's up to date, that's just for cognito user pools. There's three branches of the service now, cognito federated identities is just one.

Comment: And since this question is about accessing other AWS resources/getting temporary creds, federated identities is the service to use.